# Am I exposing too many iterators?

Tags: c++, iterator

My class can have children and so I need to expose iterators. The render class needs to reverse iterate them which is why I have reverse iterators. But is there a way to have less of these because it seems like a lot:

```
std::vector<AguiWidget*>::iterator          getChildBeginIterator();
std::vector<AguiWidget*>::reverse_iterator  getChildRBeginIterator();
std::vector<AguiWidget*>::iterator          getChildEndIterator();
std::vector<AguiWidget*>::reverse_iterator  getChildREndIterator();

std::vector<AguiWidget*>::const_iterator            getChildBeginIterator() const;
std::vector<AguiWidget*>::const_reverse_iterator    getChildRBeginIterator() const;
std::vector<AguiWidget*>::const_iterator            getChildEndIterator() const;
std::vector<AguiWidget*>::const_reverse_iterator    getChildREndIterator() const;

std::vector<AguiWidget*>::iterator          getPrivateChildBeginIterator();
std::vector<AguiWidget*>::reverse_iterator  getPrivateChildRBeginIterator();
std::vector<AguiWidget*>::iterator          getPrivateChildEndIterator();
std::vector<AguiWidget*>::reverse_iterator  getPrivateChildREndIterator();

std::vector<AguiWidget*>::const_iterator            getPrivateChildBeginIterator() const;
std::vector<AguiWidget*>::const_reverse_iterator    getPrvateChildRBeginIterator() const;
std::vector<AguiWidget*>::const_iterator            getPrivateChildEndIterator() const;
std::vector<AguiWidget*>::const_reverse_iterator    getPrivateChildREndIterator() const;
```

Thanks

Comment: why not just expose a pointer to the vector?

Comment: @madmik: that exposes implementation details and violates data hiding.

Comment: do you need the non-const forms?

Comment: publicly exposing private children doesn't seem like a great idea to me either

Comment: seems something is wrong with your design.
+ use typedefs for better readability ;)

Comment: You already exposed that your iterators are std::vector's iterators. If you change the container the interface has to be changed and so all of its users.

Comment: @Hovhannes: The typedefs would not only increase readability but also hide the underlying container type (which is an implementation detail).

Comment: If you're asking the question you're probably exposing too many

Comment: Even though [it does not seem much appreciated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267557/use-of-the-memberspace-idiom), the [memberspace technique](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1527) could perhaps make your interface clearer if you really need to provide access to both `child` and `privateChild`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Those look fine to me. Or I can't comment more precisely without knowing what exactly you're doing. But one thing you can *surely* do at any rate: why don't you use `typedef`? If you use `typedef`, you can use it outside the class as well, means in the client code, where you would use the class!

For example,

```
class sample
{
public:

  //make these typedef public so you use it from outside!
  typedef std::vector<AguiWidget*>::iterator  iterator ;
  typedef std::vector<AguiWidget*>::reverse_iterator reverse_iterator;
  typedef std::vector<AguiWidget*>::const_iterator const_iterator;
  typedef std::vector<AguiWidget*>::const_reverse_iterator const_reverse_iterator;

  iterator           child_begin();
  reverse_iterator   child_rbegin();
  iterator           child_end();
  reverse_iterator   child_rend();

  const_iterator            child_begin() const;
  const_reverse_iterator    child_rbegin() const;
  const_iterator            child_end() const;
  const_reverse_iterator    child_rend() const;
};

//Usage
sample s;
sample::iterator it= s.child_begin(); 
//see this ^^^^^^^^ how we use the typedef here!
```

This looks better! Basically the `typedef` encapsulates the implementation, because it helps you hide the implementation detail of the class; for example, what container you're using in the class, `std::vector`, `std::list`, or what? See again the *Usage* illustration above; just by looking at it you cannot say the container type, can you?

Note also that I changed the function name as well. I think that is fine. After all, STL uses just `begin` and `end` as opposed to `beginIterator`, and `endIterator`. However, the lower-case is my taste, you may still prefer upper-case for consistency!

In my opinion, the `const` functions don't make much sense, you probably would like the following set of functions if you want to expose readonly iterators!

```
const_iterator            readonly_child_begin();
const_reverse_iterator    readonly_child_rbegin();
const_iterator            readonly_child_end();
const_reverse_iterator    readonly_child_rend();


//Usage
sample s;
sample::const_iterator cit= s.readonly_child_begin(); 
//see this ^^^^^^^^ how we use the typedef here!
```

Comment: If a function that returns a `const_iterator` isn't also const, then you can never do iteration over a const container when appropriate. +1 for all the other points though.

Comment: As a sidenote, if the "private child" part is dropped, the iteration functions should probably be renamed to use standard naming: `begin` instead of `child_begin`, `end` instead of `child_end`, etc. This will make the client's life easier, and will allow the class to be used with libraries relying on this naming, such as Boost.Range.

Comment: @Luc: I would say that even if there are `private` children, I would still recommend `begin` and `end` for the regular children.

Answer (score 2):

No canned answer, but ask yourself the following questions:

- Are you planning to use each and every one of the iterators?
- Do you need the difference between a child and a private child?
- Do you need to expose something called a private child?
- Wouldn't indexing be more convenient than iteration?

Otherwise, this seems perfectly fine; iterators can require a lot of code in the class, but make it convenient to use. (You should see my polymorphic XQuery-supporting iterators for XML collections which wrap several different non-STL-compliant iterators from third-party libraries...)

The `typedef` suggestion put forward by several commenters is a good idea, because it gives better encapsulation, even though that encapsulation is not enforced by the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to cut this interface in half is to use ranges instead of begin()/end() pairs. For example, see Boost's [iterator_range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/iterator_range.html). Or you can return a reference to the container, but then you can either only get `const_iterator`s or you can let the outside modify the container, which you may not want.

Note that vector iterators are bi-directional, so you can half the number of methods again, without exposing less functionality. If you really need to use `++` instead of `--`, you can use a facade for that, for example Boost's [reverse_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/iterator/doc/reverse_iterator.html).

Note that both those things (ranges and reverse_iterator facades) are conceptually simple, and you can easily build them yourself (although doing it *properly* probably requires substantial work).

Either way, 4 functions instead of 16 sounds very reasonable to me.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this via a mixin interface:

```
template<int Tag> class IteratorRange {
  private:
    std::vector<AguiWidget*>& range;
  public:
    IteratorRange(std::vector<AguiWidget*>& range) : range(range) {}

    typedef std::vector<AguiWidget*>::iterator  iterator ;
    typedef std::vector<AguiWidget*>::reverse_iterator reverse_iterator;
    typedef std::vector<AguiWidget*>::const_iterator const_iterator;
    typedef std::vector<AguiWidget*>::const_reverse_iterator const_reverse_iterator;

    iterator           begin();
    reverse_iterator   rbegin();
    iterator           end();
    reverse_iterator   rend();
};

enum { PublicChild, PrivateChild };
class MyClass : public IteratorRange<PublicChild>, private IteratorRange<PrivateChild> {
  MyClass() : IteratorRange<PublicChild>( ??? ), IteratorRange<PrivateChild>( ??? ) { }
  typedef IteratorRange<PublicChild> Public; // For MyClass::Public::begin etc
};
```

Comment: I like this answer.  The mixin is an underused design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are doing with those iterators, you can expose some kind of visitor functions:

```
template<class UnaryFunction>
void visit(UnaryFunction & f) {
    // apply function to each element in vector
}
```

You can tweak that signature according to you needs, but it might make for a slimmer interface.

Comment: A slimmer interface, yes, but an awkward one in C++03. Besides, the OP would still need a reverse visiting members, private child visiting members...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, mostly. Standard library containers do this too. Welcome to C++!

However, I'd reconsider the "private" ones. I can't even tell what they're supposed to be, but it can't be good.

I'd also add some member type aliases with the `typedef` keyword to make the return type more encapsulated.

Answer (score -1):

You already expose std::vector::iterator, that means you already exposes many implementation details.

Return const std::vector&, const reference can reduce most of the interface and provide more functionalities. Otherwise, in future you may need to add something like getChildSize(), getXXXSize() etc.